Qubits vs Fermions, Bosons and Anyons
I found out recently that qubits are different from fermions, bosons and anyons. And, which is why we use Jordan-Wigner Transformation to map them to their fermioinc counterpart. I think I am trying to understand their natural statistics (without being mapped to fermions) and their path-integral formulation, and how they are different from the remaining particles. Also, can they be only found in 2D since fermions and bosons are only found in 3D? And, how is their production from that of Fermions/bosons/anyons?
Any answers related to the first two questions would be greatly appreciated. Also, in case if they are any textbooks along with lecture notes/articles would be very helpful.
Edit: I learnt about this during a discussion with a grad student till then I naturally assumed that spin 1/2 qubits are fermions, but the qubits are not exactly fermions unless you map them to fermions using transformation. I mentioned that this is only possible in 2D since I was reading a textbook on anyons where it was mentioned that in 2D, we can find composite particles other than fermions and bosons, so I wanted to know if qubits are like anyons or are they like the grassman variables which are not fermions but fit the fermionic statistics so we use the grassman variables to study the fermions? As an undergrad, I am still learning about these, and I got confused when I was trying to understand how different and related they are.

"I found out recently that qubits are different from fermions, bosons and anyons." In what way do you mean that they are different? A cubit can generally be many different things depending on the implementation, i.e. the label "qubit" generally refers to the role of a particle/object.

I think we need some context here.  A qubit is a quantum system of dimension 2, full stop. It's likely that you are looking at a particular implementation of a qubit (as mentioned by @MariusLadegårdMeyer), especially since you say that they can "be only found in 2D". Perhaps you are talking about anyonic qubits in topological quantum computing. Please clarify!

@MariusLadegårdMeyer, I learnt about this during a discussion with a grad student where I naturally assumed that spin 1/2 qubits are fermions, but they can be treated as fermions only when you do the transformation. Also I mentioned the dimensions since I was reading a textbook on anyons where this mentioned in 2D composite particles are possible other than fermions and bosons, so wanted to know if qubit is something like that.

Particle statistics only matters for identical particles, and qubits are by definition not identical particles.
How they are made non-identical depends on the implementation. In principle you can store one qubit as a photon polarization and another as an electron spin, but of course that method doesn't scale very far. A more plausible approach is to distinguish the qubits by position. If you have three ion traps containing ions of the same type, the wave function is technically not something like $|011\rangle$ but rather something like
$$\big( |0_01_11_2\rangle + |1_11_20_0\rangle + |1_20_01_1\rangle \pm |1_10_01_2\rangle \pm |0_01_21_1\rangle \pm |1_21_10_0\rangle \big)/\sqrt6 $$
where the subscript represents which trap that ion is in (like the address of a bit in a conventional RAM) and the sign of three of the terms depends on whether they are bosons or fermions. But it makes no difference in the quantum-circuit model: every gate acts uniformly on the six terms, and measurement doesn't care about the signs. You could extend the model with gates that mess with the addresses in ways that are sensitive to particle statistics, but there's no need for that complication since it's already computationally universal.

Could you please tell me why anyons exist only in 2D and 1D? and why are bosons and fermions only found in 3D and higher? This is not related to your answer/ question.
